# RandomFunction of the InhomogeneousPoissonProcess: unexpected behavior

Tags: random-process

For a $ 100 000 $ realization of the inhomogenous Poisson random process

```
proc = InhomogeneousPoissonProcess[a*x, x];
sim = Sign@(#["Values"])[[-1]] & /@ Table[RandomFunction[proc, {0, 1}], 1000000]
```

small part of the results has a form

`Sign[Values]`

(cca 50 values)

I think that Random function seems inevaluated, because analysis of the inner behavior of the formula

```
simTable = Table[RandomFunction[buyProc, {0, 1}], 1000000]; 
(Transpose@{Sign@(#["Values"])[[-1]] & /@ simTable, simTable}) // DeleteCases[#, {_Integer, _}] &
```

leads to repetition sequence of

`{Sign["Values"], RandomFunction[InhomogeneousPoissonProcess[10 t,t], {0, 1}]}`

This means that in several cases the function has not been evaluated at all. Not that the random part of the results would not be further processed (excepted result is {0 or 1, TemporalData}.

Where is the error and how to treat it?